# How to use Subtotal function in Excel table with filters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table where I have control values per month. This table also contains a column to show the total the total due to that month, so that mean if my value in January is 5 and the value in February is 10, the 'total to date' will be 5 for January and 15 for February.

Now I want to use filters in this table, so if I unselect the January line, the 'total to date' have to be 10 for February.

My problem is that the filter does not seem to work when using Subtotal function because not all of my values appear when I use this function. Moreover, after I unselect one of the lines, I can't select it again.

This is my original table

[image: This is my original table]

This is how the filter looks like

[image: How the filter looks like]

This is what happens after apply a filter

[image: What happens after a filter]

This is the code I used to build the table:

```
'Activate Sheet3
Worksheets("Completed Proposals").Activate

'Insert a new column for calculated values
Insert_Column

'Set the table address, name, and style
rng3 = "A2:E" & Sheet3.range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
Set tbl3 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, range(rng3), , xlYes)
tbl3.name = "MainTable3"
tbl3.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"

'Change Sheet3 rows' height
Rows("3:" + CStr(Sheet3.range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)).RowHeight = 15
```

This is the function I call in the previous code:

```
Sub Insert_Column()
'Insert a column in the Sheet3 for specific use

Dim cellRange   As String

'Set the range to fill
cellRange = "E3:E" & Sheet3.range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

'Set column description'
range("E2").Value = "Total To Date"

'Set the new value to the range
For Each c1 In Sheet3.range(cellRange).Cells
    c1.Value = "=Subtotal(109,D3:D" + CStr(c1.Row) + ")"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hit the button `clear filters from "value"`. Can you select previously filtered out columns again?

Comment: @CBRF23, no, I can't

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how the table is generated - it doesn't include the last row (even in your first filter the last value is missing). I added an extra row to the range and it works as expected:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub makeTable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, tblRng As Range

    InsertColumn   'calculated values

    With Sheet3

        Set tblRng = .Range("A2:E" & .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row + 1)

        Set tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tblRng, , xlYes, , "TableStyleMedium15")

        With tbl
            .Name = "MainTable3"
            .Range.Rows(3).RowHeight = 15
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim cellRange As String, cel As Variant

    With Sheet3

        .Range("E2").Value = "Total To Date" 'description

        cellRange = "E3:E" & .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

        For Each cel In .Range(cellRange).Cells
            cel.Value = "=Subtotal(109,D3:D" & cel.Row & ")"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

maybe it will help